# ArangoDB Foxx Service ReferenceError: URL is not defined

Tags: arangodb, foxx, arangodb-foxx

I'm trying to install a service to ArangoDB with the Foxx CLI but I get an error when using `joi` as a dependency. The full stack trace is below:

```sh
Server encountered errors executing a JavaScript file:

@ node_modules/@sideway/address/lib/domain.js:14:21
  12 |     tldSegmentRx: /^[a-zA-Z](?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?$/,
  13 |     domainSegmentRx: /^[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?$/,
> 14 |     URL: Url.URL || URL                                                                 // $lab:coverage:ignore$    
     |                     ^
  15 | };
  16 | 
  17 | 
ArangoError 3103: failed to invoke module
File: /tmp/arangod_bepCMN/services-tmp-1-4156953835/node_modules/@sideway/address/lib/domain.js
Reason: ReferenceError: URL is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/arangod_bepCMN/services-tmp-1-4156953835/node_modules/@sideway/address/lib/domain.js:14:21)
    at Module._compile (/usr/share/arangodb3/js/common/bootstrap/modules.js:606:8)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (/usr/share/arangodb3/js/common/bootstrap/modules.js:624:12)
    at Module.load (/usr/share/arangodb3/js/common/bootstrap/modules.js:551:36)
    at Function.Module._load (/usr/share/arangodb3/js/common/bootstrap/modules.js:496:16)
    at require (/usr/share/arangodb3/js/common/bootstrap/modules.js:98:21)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/arangod_bepCMN/services-tmp-1-4156953835/node_modules/joi/lib/types/string.js:4:16)        
    at Module._compile (/usr/share/arangodb3/js/common/bootstrap/modules.js:606:8)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (/usr/share/arangodb3/js/common/bootstrap/modules.js:624:12)
    at Module.load (/usr/share/arangodb3/js/common/bootstrap/modules.js:551:36)

For details check the arangod server logs.
```

This [issue](https://github.com/arangodb/foxx-cli/issues/45#issuecomment-698251386) states that the error might be caused by the `ignore file` but I'm not using
a `.foxxignore` file at all. Any idea what else could cause this error?

Below is my `package.json` with all the scripts. The `install:service`, `upgrade:service` and `setup` all throw this error.

```json
{
  "name": "auth",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p .",
    "install:service": "npm run build && foxx install /auth --server dev --database party",
    "upgrade:service": "npm run build && foxx upgrade /auth --server dev --database party",
    "setup": "foxx server set dev http://root:password@localhost:8529 --database party && npm run install:service"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "joi": "^17.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/arangodb": "^3.5.13",
    "@types/joi": "^17.2.3",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.6",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "typescript": "^4.4.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be late, but I've found that the newer versions of [joi](https://github.com/sideway/joi/tree/v14.3.1) to be incompatible with the one installed underneath the covers (v14).

Here's what works for me (excerpt from `package.json`):

```js
{
    "dependencies": {
        "chai": "^4.3.4",
        "joi": "^14.3.1"
    }
}
```